# How to implement app links on android marshmallow?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, applinks

App links are being changed in Android 6.0, so that Android has a greater awareness of which apps can open content directly, instead of stopping users every time with the dialog box.

How do i implement it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well yes App Links is new and cool features on Android **Marshmallow 6.0**.  which lets a aster way of opening website links for domains that you own.

There are two Conditions need to meet for applinks:

1. Add `<intent-filter>` for urls
2. Verify ownership of domain

**Make sure you have at least 1 activity with intent filter in it.**

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.domain.com"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.domain.com" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Intent filters** for app links must declare an `android:scheme` value of `http`, `https`, or both. The filter must not declare any other schemes. The filter must also include the `android.intent.action.VIEW` and `android.intent.category.BROWSABLE` category names.

> Don't forget to add `android:autoVerify="true"` attribute on
>   `<intent-filter>` This will tell the system to start the domain
>   verification while the app install on the device.

Now to associate your site with your app you need to add **Digital Asset Link JSON file** on your site. Exactly the same path under your website root directory

```
https://www.domain.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```

> The following example assetlinks.json file grants link-opening rights
>   to a `com.example Android app`:

**This is what JSON file look like:**

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.example",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["14:6D:E9:83:C5:73:06:50:D8:EE:B9:95:2F:34:FC:64:16:A0:83:42:E6:1D:BE:A8:8A:04:96:B2:3F:CF:44:E5"]
  }
}]
```

Just have to replace the value `"package_name":` and  `"sha256_cert_fingerprints":` 
**Leave others as it is.**

> Make sure the file you create is accessible over `HTTPS` protocal

Now you can test the app, for tests you can follow the instruction from [android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html) blog